# Unable to access to Magento Connect Manager

Tags: admin

When I tried to logged into the Magento Connect Manager with my Magento admin ID and password, I am unable to log in and come out with the message  "Access Denied". As I am the only administrator of the store, how should I grant the access right to myself? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to

> System->Permissions->Roles

and click Administrators role.

Check your Role Resources settings just in case, Resource Access dropdown should be already set to All for administrators.

Without changing anything just click “Save Role” button, so that Magento re-saves all permissions.

You should be able to access your new extension now without problems.

Try this [LINK](https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/651-unable-to-login-into-the-magento-backend) it ha a lot of info on this point

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I got the similar solutions when I do my google search. However, I am unable to find the "permission" when I navigate to "system", is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Try creating your own admin programmatically:
http://santoshyadavcse.wordpress.com/2013/02/04/magento-create-admin-user-programmatically/

Comment: Thanks for you help again. I believe I have successfully create a new account through inserting the script into the sql server. However, I got the access denied message when I try to log into the admin panel. Is there any way I can grant access to these username in the sql server?

Comment: I have updated my answer check that link, hopefully that will work

Comment: Hello, here's what I have done but still not successful: I have added the script in a text and name it as test.txt. I uploaded the txt file to the root directory of of magento through ftp. I run this test.txt file in my IE and the file can be loaed successfully. I got the message" Invalid User Name or Password" this time when I log into the admin panel page.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. There may be corruption in your magento connect config file.

To fix it, delete or rename the file "[install path]/downloader/connect.cfg"

The file will be recreated after you successfully log in again.